# Converting Oracle code to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

If I have a .php file with some Oracle code previously accessing a Oracle DB, but have setup a MySQL DB and want to edit the existing .php file to be compatible with the MySQL DB, how would I go about doing this? Do I have to manually go through each line and search for the equivalent MySQL statement, and if so, is there a library I can access that gives me the Oracle to MySQL equivalent command?

Answer (score 1):

There is this website with a good compilation of tips and tools to help you out on this task: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql

Comment: I tried the website and couldn't get it to work for what I want to do. Here is an example.

I want to make:
    $myStatement = oci_parse($myConnection, $myQuery);

to turn into the SQL equivalent for the function "oci_parse" which is an oracle command.

Comment: Well, of course my friend. There are some functions that are exclusive to a certain database. It's up to you to discover if you can achieve the same functionality with another db. :)